# How to find out index in numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have saved the Urdu text in `numpy` array and I want to find out the index number, however I am not able to do that. This is my code

```
import numpy as np
wordsList = np.load('urduwords.npy') 
wordIndex= list(wordsList).index("آئندہ")
```

When I print the `wordsList` I can see the word exist there

```
    print(wordsList)

['\ufeffکرخت', 'آؤٹ', 'آؤں', 'آئرلینڈ', 'آئرن']
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a [where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function which will give you the index value of the output. By the way, if you are using the latest numpy version then it will automatically detect the type.

Try this

```
import numpy as np

wordsList =np.array(['\ufeffکرخت', 'آؤٹ', 'آؤں', 'آئرلینڈ', 'آئرن',"آئندہ"])
arr_index = np.where(wordsList == 'آئندہ')
print(arr_index)
```

Comment: it is giving empty array (array([], dtype=int64),)

Comment: update numpy "pip install --upgrade numpy" cus I tried it on my pc and it worked for me maybe the data in 'urduwords.npy' isn't correct or your code is not loading the file properly